# How work Post method on View?

Tags: android, post, view, concurrency

I have some problem with this code, here you can find a simplified version of the problem.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private WebView wv = null;
private CountDownLatch signal = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            signal.countDown();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
    wv.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/MySample.html");
        }
    });

    try {
        signal.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ElaborateAll(2);
}
```

}

In debug the code doesn't reach ElaborateAll(2).

Every help will be apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is:

1. Adding a custom WebViewClient with a CountDownLatch
2. Posting a Runnable to the UI thread
3. Blocking the UI thread

And that's it, your execution stops there, the Runnable will not be executed and thus you'll never loadUrl(); remove the CountDownLatch and the program will loadUrl() as expected.